# SVG Elliptical Arc with D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Recently I have written a project with D3, so I need an Elliptical Arc with `innerRadius` and `outerRadius`. However I don't know how to draw Elliptical Arc.The point that I have to mention is a Circular Arc is different with an Elliptical Arc, the Circular Arc will draw with just a radius that could be `innerRadius` and `outerRadius`, but the Elliptical Arc have two radius `rx , ry`  that could be `innerRadiusX`and `outerRadiusX` and `innerRadiusY`and `outerRadiusY`, Actually I want to draw an Ellipse with `d3.svg.arc()` with all `arc` function details such as `startAngle` and `endAngle`. I don't know if there is any way to draw it with these Attributes :

```
attr={cx:20 , cy:20 , innerRadiusX:100 , outerRadiusX: 200 ,
       innerRadiusY:50,outerRadiusY:100,startAngel:0.5*Math.PI , endAngle: 1.5*Math.PI }
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717652/making-an-arc-in-d3-js

Comment: Thank you dear Mark for your comment but my question is different. I need to draw an Ellipse with ' d3.svg.arc() '.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, I think you can use SVG paths.
[DashingD3](http://www.dashingd3js.com) has a good explanation about it [there](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js).

> W3 then provides an analogy relating pen and paper roughly as follows:
>   Imagine that a pen is put on a piece of paper. The pen will touch the
>   paper in only one point. The pen is now moved to another point. The
>   path between the two points can be a straight line or a curve. The
>   curve can be an arc, a cubic Bézier curve or a quadratic Bézier curve.
>   Which means that you can use an SVG Path to make any type of SVG
>   shape.

See "curveto".
Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you dear laugri, after reading your helpful Reference I realized I have to implement my own function to create an elliptical arc as it was mentioned. in this case I must to use elliptical arc path d value. thank you again.

Comment: Is there any Implemented function that return an Elliptical arc like Circular arc?