# Bend SVG `<g>` around Curve

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graphics, vector-graphics

I'm using D3.js to draw some SVG `<path>`s in a straight line. All of these elements are contained in a `<g>` with the same vertical transformation.

[image]

I'd like to "wrap" these elements around a circular arc. At the end, each rectangle should become a small segment of the arc, and the vertical lines will point into the center of the circle.

I realize that I could probably do this in an arc from the beginning: drawing thick circle segments end-to-end instead of rectangles, for example. This, however, sounds like a lot of math and calculation, especially for someone new to SVG.

Is there a way to transform these elements onto a curve *post hoc*, meaning I could use the code I have which draws these rectangles—maybe by changing the `transform` attribute? If there's an external SVG library (though I've looked with no success), I'd also consider using that.

Comment: That's what the arc drawing command is for. It's not that complicated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than using the path arc command `A`—though not quite what I was hoping for in that it can't morph elements arranged in a line around a circle—I found `d3.arc()` (formerly `d3.svg.arc()`).

```
canvas.selectAll(".xContainer")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(...)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(element, index) { return colorForSize(element[4]); })
    .attr("d", function(element, index) {

        var arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(iR)
            .outerRadius(iR + 10)
            .startAngle(element[1])
            .endAngle(element[2])
            .cornerRadius(isRounded ? 8 : 0);

        return arc();

    });
```

Thanks, [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718028/2809263).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand. Does this allow you to modify the `<g>` post-hoc as asked, or does this just draw fresh arcs?

Comment: @elijahcarrel Draws fresh arcs. I haven't found a way to bend a `<g>` post-hoc; please lmk if you do.