# Warp an SVG in JavaScript into an arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry, transform

I saw a d3 helper function which can create an svg arc: [making an arc in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717652/making-an-arc-in-d3-js/12718028#12718028)

Is there a way to bend an existing svg into an arc in d3.js? If not, how can it be done in JavaScript? The initial image could be a square with negative space inside that makes a silhouette of something like a cat.

I included a drawing of what I want. I eventually want to make more and create a ring, and then concentric rings of smaller transformations.

[image]

Comment: Can you draw what you are after?

Comment: I experimented with dvg.js, and it is able to warp svg's by adding a lot of points and turning lines into curves. I updated and added an image of what I'm going for.

Comment: there is a way but not for all primitives. This could be done on `<path>` with all its entities apart elliptic arc. So if you convert whole **SVG** to `<path>` containing just lines and beziers you can transform such polygons into bended bezier cubics But that is not as easy as it sounds ...

Comment: What you want would require a non-affine transform. Non-affine transforms are not supported by SVG.

Comment: Reminds me of https://cindyjs.org/gallery/cindygl/Jugglers/ where you can achieve layouts similar to this. Generally you'd be looking for conformal transformations (preserve angles), or more specifically for Möbius transformations (map lines and circles to lines and circles). SVG doesn't support these. You can surely approximate this, though. One way would be discrete conformal maps, which map triangle meshes in an almost conformal way, and provide a projective transformation to interpolate the interior of the triangles in a way that's continuous at the seams.

Comment: What I'm looking for is more like an example on the d3 page, where each one of those blocks on the circular grid is an svg that has been warped to the shape of the square: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/846710
It's hard to see on that example, but each block is warped somewhat, and would be more visible if there were less blocks.

Comment: @VagueExplanation: That example does not have one SVG image per block. It's just a bunch of tiny paths, and the code specifies how to draw each line. That's quite far from transforming a more complex SVG image, as your question suggests.

Comment: Check out [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/LiangGou/30e9af0d54e1d5287199) of a bar chart transitioning to a donut. The basic idea is that you create an arc segment with a very very large radius so that the segment appears to be a rectangle.  you can then transition to a smaller donut segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think conformal mapping is the way to go. As an example, I have started with the original square source and the circularly arranged (and appropriately warped) squares using conformal mapping. See the [Circular Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM6l3.png) and the [Corresponding Square Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ6n7.png). Note, however, that I first converted the SVG source into a png image, and then applied conformal mapping transformation to each pixel in the png image. If anyone has a method of mapping entirely in the SVG domain [where the source uses only straight lines and bezier curves], pl. let us know!

I am not able to provide the code -- it is too complex and uses proprietary libraries). Here is a way to do it.

In order to compute the conformal mapping, I used a complex algebra library. JEP is one example. For each pixel in the OUTPUT image, you set Z = (x, y) where (x, y) are the coordinates of the pixel and Z is a complex variable with real part x and imaginary part y. Then you compute NEWZ = f(Z) where f is any function you want. for circle, I used an expression such as "(ln(Z*1)/pi)*6-9" where the log (ln) provides circularity, the 6 implies 6 bent squares in a circle and the -9 is a scaling factor to center and place the image. From the (X, Y) values of the NEWZ, you look up the old image to find the pixel to place in the new image. When the (X, Y) values are outside the size of the old image, I just use tiling of the old image to determine the pixel. When X and Y are fractional (non-integer) you average the neighbors in a weighted way.

Comment: Could you actually add the code that achieved what you display in your images?